# Rust(pyo3) calls python(yolov8) blocking

Tags: python, rust, yolov5, yolov8, pyo3

#### Problem brief description

I wrote the prediction for YOLOv8 in Python and called it in Pyo3, but it got stuck during the prediction phase. It's normal to execute the Python script separately。

#### You can clone this code from here:

`https://github.com/Rainweic/ColorClassifier`

**you need to change the path of image**

#### Code brief description

**python code:**

```py
# yolov8.py
from ultralytics import YOLO


class YoloV8:

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None

    def load_model(self, model_path):
        self.model = YOLO(model_path)

    def infer(self, img_path):
        res = self.model(img_path)
        return res


yolov8 = YoloV8()
```

**rust code:**

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

static PYTHON_FILE_PATH: &str = include_str!("yolov8.py");

pub struct DetModule {
    pub instance: Option<Py<PyAny>>
}

impl DetModule {
    pub fn new() -> Self {

        let mut det_module = Self { instance: None };

        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let det: &PyModule = PyModule::from_code(py, PYTHON_FILE_PATH, "", "")
                .expect("Load det module error");
            let instance: Py<PyAny> = det.getattr("yolov8")
                .expect("Get obj yolov8 failed").into();
            det_module.instance = Some(instance);
        });

        det_module
    }

    pub fn load_model(&mut self, model_file: &str) {
        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let args = (model_file,);
            self.instance.as_ref().unwrap()
                .call_method1(py, "load_model", args)
                .expect("Load model {model_file} failed");
        });
    }

    pub fn infer(&self, img_path: &str) -> Option<PyObject> {
        let mut infer_res = None;

        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let args = (img_path,);
            let res = self.instance.as_ref().unwrap()
                .call_method1(py, "infer", args)
                .expect("Infer error, img path: {img_path}");
            // infer_res = Some(res);
        });

        infer_res
    }
}


fn main() {

    let mut yolo_module = model::DetModule::new();
    yolo_module.load_model("yolov8n.pt");
    let res = yolo_module.infer("/Users/new/Downloads/car.png");
    match res {
        None => {}
        Some(res) => println!("res: {:?}", res)
    };
}
```

It doesn't feel like a deadlock, because when I run the py file alone it's predicted, and I add breakpoints with debugger and can't see exactly what line is stuck

Comment: res = self.model(img_path)   <----- block here

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code fails with a TypeError, and after fixing it by giving the module a name it works correctly.

Comment: I posted the project's github address, thank you for helping me